# Recursive Query CTE in SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite, recursive-query

I have the Following table Structure. (I am new to SQL Lite)

```
create table Relations 
(
Code int,
ParentCode int ,
fname text
)
GO
insert into Relations values(1,null,'A');
insert into Relations values(2,null,'B');
insert into Relations values(3,2,'C');
insert into Relations values(4,3,'D');
```

I want to get the initial parent of Code =4 : 
i.e. values 2 null B

I am not able to figure out how to write a recursive query in sqllite.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a version issue..
This query was not working & was getting a syntax Error.
I upgraded From 3.7.17 To 3.8.7.4 version & it worked..

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  works(Code,Parent) AS (
   Select Code,ParentCode from Relations a where a.Code=4
    UNION
    SELECT Relations.Code, Relations.ParentCode FROM Relations , works
     WHERE Relations.Code=works.Parent
  )
SELECT * FROM works where Parent is null
```